# AWS authentication to Vault

Tags: aws-sdk, hashicorp-vault

We're using Vault to store our application secrets and config. When our app (Java) starts, a script does all the magic of getting the secrets and config from Vault and storing them locally for the application to read. The script is authenticating to Vault using AWS IAM role.

Now we're getting to a situation where the application needs to read secrets from Vault on the go, not just on startup. For that purpose, I need it to be able to do the authentication pretty much on every request. It's worth mentioning that the app might also run on the developer machine, so whatever authentication done - it needs to work on the EC2 instance as well as the local development environment.

I'm currently leaning towards creating a username and password, store them in Vault for the application to get when starting up. Then the application could use that username/password to authenticate to Vault when it needs.
I'm also considering AppRole, but can't really see any real advantage to it over simple user/password setup.

What's the best solution for this use-case? Any advise would be highly appreciated!

Thanks,
Yosi

Answer (score 0):

The AWS recommendation for storing secrets is to use [AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-paramstore.html).

Software running on an Amazon EC2 instance with an assigned **Role** can use those credentials to access the Parameter Store to retrieve application secrets.

The Parameter Store can also be used **outside of EC2**, but some AWS credentials will still be needed to authenticate to the Parameter Store.